# Google map superimposed on an image makes the image disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a google map superimposed on an image and when the page loads, the google map essentially causes the image to disappear. I'm using bootstrap. My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div id="map-canvas">
    <img id="image-formatting" src="some_image.png" alt="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant css:

```
#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 280px;
  background-color: #CCC
}

.image-formatting {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 65%;
}
```

I want the image to appear behind the map. When I remove the map, the image is exactly where I want it, behind the div. Once the map is initialized, the image disappears.

Comment: The API removes any content from the map-container when it creates a map. You must achieve the desired result with the image placed outside of `#map-canvas`

Answer (score 0):

As @Dr.Molle says in the comments, the Maps API will remove your content when it initializes. It doesn't want anything in the way of it's pretty maps.

Just a suggestion, but a nice easy way to achieve what you are after would be to place your map container over a `div` with a background image (excuse all the inline styles, it's a quick and nasty example)

```html
<div style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/1000/300/animals');height:300px;width:100%;">
  <div id="map-container" style="height:200px;width:500px;background-color:#663399;color:white;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center;">I'm a map</div>
</div>
```

Now that the map container is in it's own div, you image will say where it is, behind the map. Obviously this comes with downsides as well, but it's one way to achieve what you are after.